# Need to execute my SQL queries in my model to display the result as API in django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-views

**Model**

```
class Consolidated(models.Model):
    
    emp_name=models.ForeignKey(Users,on_delete=CASCADE)
    proj_name=models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    custom_name=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE)
    Cons_date=models.ForeignKey(Add_Timelog, on_delete=CASCADE)
    bill_no_bill=models.ForeignKey(Users,related_name="billable_and_non_billable+", on_delete=CASCADE)
    hour_spent = models.ForeignKey(Add_Timelog,related_name="hour_spent", on_delete=CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.emp_name)
```

**viewset**

```
    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAdminUser,)
    queryset = models.Consolidated.objects.raw("select public.App_add_job.id, employee_name, billable_and_non_billable, client_id, project_id from public.App_add_job join public.App_users on public.App_add_job.employee_name_id = public.App_users.id")
    serializer_class=serializers.Consolidated_serializers
```

I have a sql query updated in my viewset and i dont know how to run that query in my API model to display the table values in the api. kindly help me to change the code for the model to execute the sql queries in that Consolidated model.

Comment: don't use raw query for this, django have a built in orm to do these kind of queries

Comment: can you please share me on how to built a orm for this query model, as iam new to django i had stucked on this.

Comment: did you went through the django tutorials? it's go through the ORM apis and how to use it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

Comment: can you please update me any base code for the above example which i mentioned, because still its confusing